# Cannot find string

Tags: java, string

I'm just messing around with code to see what I can do and what I can't do and so I'm creating a VERY simple log in program and for some reason it can't seem to find one of the strings. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Username: ");
        String user = input.next();
        System.out.print('\f');

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Pass: ");
            String pass = input.next();
            System.out.print('\f');

            System.out.print("Password Again: ");
            String pass2 = input.next();
            System.out.print('\f');

            if (pass.equals(pass2)) {
                System.out.println("*Passwords Match*");
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            } else if (!pass.equals(pass2)) {
                 System.out.println("*Passwords don't match, please try again*");
                 System.out.println("");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("User: " + user);
        System.out.println("Pass: " + pass);
    }
}
```

It can't find the string pass. I don't know if it's a reserved word or not but when I tried changing the string to password instead of pass it still couldn't find it. Any help would be nice

Comment: Declare pass on the same scope as your user.

Comment: That is, `pass` is being declared inside the `while` loop. When the `while` loop ends, the application can no longer access `pass`. The solution is, as @SajalDutta says, to declare `pass` at the same time that you declare `user`: `String pass;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `pass` outside of where it can be used.
If you declare it within the main method, your code will work.
Basically, anything that is being used outside of the scope of the `while` loop must be initialized somewhere. As stated, you don't have to worry about `pass2` being declared elsewhere since its main functionality resides purely within the scope of the loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pass,user;
        System.out.print("Username: ");
        user = input.next();
        System.out.print('\f');

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Pass: ");
            pass = input.next();
            System.out.print('\f');

            System.out.print("Password Again: ");
            String pass2 = input.next();
            System.out.print('\f');

            if (pass.equals(pass2)) {
                System.out.println("*Passwords Match*");
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            } else if (!pass.equals(pass2)) {
                 System.out.println("*Passwords don't match, please try again*");
                 System.out.println("");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("User: " + user);
        System.out.println("Pass: " + pass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are trying to use the variable `pass` outside of its defined scope. That is, it is defined within the `while` loop and you are trying to use it outside of the loop. This will give you a compile-time error as it is invalid code.

Compare this with the `user` variable which is defined outside of the loop (ie. before) and can therefore be used after it.

I'd move the definition of `pass` to immediately after that of `user`. That should solve your problem. (The definition of `pass2` can stay within the loop.)

Comment: How do I call it then?

Answer (score 1):

your variable `pass` is in the while loop and you are trying to access it outside the loop. The variables scope is only within the loop